# error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector when printing an array within a function (C)

Tags: arrays, c

Hi there I'm trying to print an array but I keep getting this error out (error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector) whenever I try and print from a function. As its a time I want only the data within the array not the position of the data as well.
***It also works if its not in a function.

My code is as follows:

```
int currenttime[] = {00,00,00};
int i;
void outputtime(int currenttime)
{   
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++) 
    {
     printf("%d ", i, currenttime[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
outputtime(currenttime);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void outputtime(currenttime)` - what type is `currenttime`? It seems to be missing... Also, is `i` a global variable?

Comment: Turn your warnings up. `currenttime` is an implicit `int`, something that was scrapped in (I think) C99. I assume you want it to be `const int currenttime[3]`.

Comment: What resource are you using to learn C? I wonder, because if it taught you to create variables likes that (without a type) then you should scrap it and find something else.

Comment: Another detail: `printf("%d ", i, currenttime[i]);` - You have only _one_ conversion in there, `%d` for `i`. What about the one for `currenttime[i]`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry i forgot to add it, current time is declared else where as an integer "int currenttime[] = {00,00,00};"  and I is also declared earlier:"int i;" and I have no clue what a global variable is to be honest with you. This is my university lectures code I've reworked for my own.

Comment: @TateClayton  Such info should go into the question. The question is now closed because lack of detail but I added your new information to it and voted to reopen the question. It may or may not be reopened though. Btw, how are you currently calling this function?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah sorry forgot to put it in, thank you though

Comment: @TateClayton No problem. After asking a question here, be prepared to stick around for 15 minutes to see if someone wants clarifications etc. and edit the question if you agree that you could make it more clear. Otherwise the question will get closed pretty quickly which is a bummer because opening the question again usually takes a lot longer than it takes to close it :-)

Comment: ... and how are you currently calling the function `outputtime`? You could make a [mre] to clarify all these things.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ill do that now and add it on thank you.

Comment: The code you show should produce warnings when building. When you call the function you pass a *pointer* (`int *`), but the function argument is declared as a plain `int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How do I convert between the two? ive got warnings similar to this else where as well

Comment: It is a really bad idea to have a function parameter with the same name as a global.  In this case you have them declared as different types.  Having two variables with the same name and different types is a recipe for failure.  If you want it to compile change `void outputtime(int currenttime)` to `void outputtime(int *currenttime)` but if I were you I would make your `currenttime` glabal variable local to `main()` and your `i` global variable local to `outputtime()` - there is no reason to have global variables here at all.

Comment: "It also works if its not in a function." I doubt that. See my answer why. It explains that after fixing the immediate problem you get output of `i` instead of `currenttime[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide parameters to match the prototype of a called function.
Either you keep the prototype and call accordingly, or you adapt the prototype.

This is giving a pointer to int (to which the use of an array identifier in a function call decays) to a function which you declared to expect an int.

```
outputtime(currenttime);
```

From the context I conclude that in this case your call is actually what you want to do, so the prototype needs to be adapted to declare a parameter of pointer to `int`.

```
void outputtime(int* currenttime)
```

But that gives an output of "1 2 3".
This happens because in your call to `printf()` you provide two values (`i` and `currenttime[i]`), with only one being used by the format specifier `"%d "`.

Either you want to print the two values and need to adapt the specifier

```
printf("%d:%d, ", i, currenttime[i]);
```

which gets you an output of

```
0:0, 1:0, 2:0,
```

or you remove the first value to only output the content of the array.

```
printf("%d ", currenttime[i]);
```

for an output of

```
0 0 0
```

In case you now wonder why your init of the array of

```
int currenttime[] = {00,00,00};
```

only gets you single 0s for each part; that is because the `00` are identical to `0`. If you want to change how a 0 is printed, you need to use other features of `printf()`, after reading the details in the specification.